# How can I create side tabs within a Chrome DevTools extension panel?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm creating a devtools extension. I've already done chrome.devtools.panels.create to create a new panel. Now I want to add side tabs within that panel, imitating the layout structure of the Audits or Profiles panels. Is that something that's done completely with custom HTML, JS and CSS or are there tools within Chrome for doing that? When I see other extensions do this, they seem to be pretty consistent with the Chrome UI, so that's why I suspect it may not be custom, but I haven't seen anything related to that when I searched the docs for it.

An example extension that I'd like to imitate is the Ember Inspector: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en

Comment: it's not an answer, but you could try inspecting those extensions which do look native.

Comment: @kalman I did try inspecting them, but there is so much unfamiliar going on, that without documentation, I can't really make sense of it.